# How to do retopology for narrow spaces?

Tags: retopology

I want to do retopology for a model.
I don't know, how I should handle the space between teeth and the mouth.

This is my model:

[image]

And I'm refering to this space:

[image]

It's almost impossible to move the camera, so that I can do the retopolgy "inside" the mouth.

It just looks like this:

[image]

I just have no idea, how I should do the retopology for those spaces.

Is there a way?

Comment: retopology itself is a huge thing to explain, I think that there are better places to ask this question but maybe you can just select the bottom half of the mouth, separate it to another object and hide it... start retopology of your top side of the mouth and then invert it and finish bottom (not the best way but definitely the easiest one)

Comment: It would be better to plan ahead in the first place and model stuff like this so that it needs no retopology. The teeth are(or should be) all similar, at least as far as topology goes. It could have been the same object deformed in different ways with clean topology in the first place. Planning ahead could save time and an unpleasant repetitive work.

Comment: To you want to retopologize because you want to animate for example? In that case it would be better to have a mouth that is fully opened. You could retopologize your whole object except the mouth then keep on modelling the mouth itself without the high-poly as target

Comment: Thanks for the ideas guys. Ill see what works!